# How can I choose the default application for opening files in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, kubuntu

When I download an MP3 file - I click on it in a download list and Firefox opens Rhythmbox to play it. I want it to open Audacious for the job though. I can't find Rhythmbox neither under *Preferences » Associations*, nor in `about:config`.

Where else should I try to find it?

Same thing for PDFs — it opens them in Evince while I prefer Okular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

For example, for an MP3 file — click on some MP3 file on the Internet or mailed to you as an attachment. Firefox will ask what to do with it. Open it with your favorite player — and from this time on Firefox will open MP3s with it.

Comment: How did Firefox ask you what to do with the file when you clicked on it? I thought it opened the wrong player automatically… which is what you stated in your question.

Comment: Well it asks what to do with the thing: save, or open. In open thing -- You can choose an app, where as if You click the file on the list of downloaded files -- it doesn't ask anything and just opens with the default app.

Answer (score 0):

It's either in Options -> Applications, or in your default Open-with settings. In my opinion, it's because of Firefox's settings, but the second one is just for guarantee.

Comment: I double-checked my open-with settings. It says Audacious for mp3. Yet FF opens downloaded mp3s from download list with rythmbox.

Comment: Then, I'm right about this. You should change the settings about file types in Options -> Applications. Find the Content Type, and change the default program to whatever you like. Take care.